# Pumpkin pie in a crust that requires a shorter cooking time

Tags: pie, crust

I'm trying to make a pumpkin pie in a crust I normally use for cheesecake, it's about 1/8th inch thick, and bakes for 25 min @ 325 and I usually top it with a nonbaked cheesecake filling of cream cheese and gelatin.

I want to top it with a pumpkin pie filling recipe that cooks at 350 for almost an hour.

Will it burn or overcook inside a springform with the filling completely covering it?

Is it possible to reconcile the two? Should I just plan on somehow baking them separately and then stacking?

This is the crust:

```
115 grams unsalted butter at room temperature
30 grams dark brown sugar
30 milliliters honey
125 grams all-purpose flour
35 grams whole-wheat flour
7 grams unsweetened cocoa powder
3 grams kosher salt
1 gram ground cinnamon
```

Comment: I just meant it's not a regular pie crust and only bakes for 1/3 of the time as the filling. Sorry, I'll post the recipe. For some reason I had thought it was against the rules here.

Comment: Asking for recipes ("recipe requests") is off topic, discussing an existing recipe to evaluate or eliminate problems is absolutely ok.

Comment: Is the crust normally baked empty? If so, the baking time of the crust alone probably doesn't matter much when baked filled.

Comment: I would agree with @Catija that the baking time shouldn't be an issue when you top the crust with filling. However, I would probably increase the ingredients so that your crust is closer to 1/4 in thickness and would pre-bake for 10-12 minutes before adding the filling.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the advice. Would a water bath be advisable here?

Comment: I don't think it's necessary, since the pumpkin filling would be sturdier, in a sense, than fillings which need the gentler bain marie.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, it seems like your crust recipe is basically trying to create a buttery graham cracker crust from scratch, plus cocoa powder (that sounds interesting).  Here are the ingredients of Nabisco graham crackers, from their website:

```
UNBLEACHED ENRICHED FLOUR (...), GRAHAM FLOUR (WHOLE GRAIN WHEAT FLOUR),
SUGAR, SOYBEAN OIL, HONEY, LEAVENING (...), SALT, SOY LECITHIN, ARTIFICIAL FLAVOR.
```

So I expect that you'd be fine baking it (creating the consistency of grahams, which are cooked) and then topping it and cooking again, just as if you used crumbled graham crackers in the first place.  Not seeing your crust, though, my only concern will be if it's not dry enough to stand up to the moisture you'll pour on top with a pumpkin pie recipe (a custard).

All that being said, I'd be very tempted to just crumble grahams per usual and add a little cocoa powder to simulate your crust.